# shredding a particular drive in my PC?

Tags: file-shredding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Erasing data before selling a computer](https://superuser.com/questions/4678/erasing-data-before-selling-a-computer)

Hi,
  I want to shred a particular drive in my PC and i dont want to recover any files from that drive...Is it possible??If so den which tool(best shredding tool) is best on its own??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See similar question: [How to delete my hard drive safely?](https://superuser.com/questions/52905/how-to-delete-my-hard-drive-safely/53091)

Comment: In future it would be best if you dropped that as a comment, at 3k you can vote to close as a dupe. If you wanted to flag for mod, feel free, we welcome such.