# Program to wipe HD?

Tags: hard-drive, security, external-hard-drive, secure-erase, wipe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Securely format a hard drive](https://superuser.com/questions/62251/securely-format-a-hard-drive)
>   [How to wipe a USB hard drive](https://superuser.com/questions/86694/how-to-wipe-a-usb-hard-drive)

What is a freeware app i can use to wipe a HD?
I have two

1) My external which is <1yr old and is reported 'failure' on disk health checks (maybe i wont bother wiping this?)

2) My laptop which i may send in for repairs or get it replace. It currently is under warranty.

I think i could just write a program that writes random bytes to the HD until i have no space. Would this be good enough? (This app wont work on the broken/external HD tho).

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of apps for this; don't bother writing one yourself. To completely wipe the HDD, you'll have to do it at boot, or the program would overwrite itself. Here's [one program](http://www.dban.org/) which says it'll "nuke" the hard drive.

Depends how sensitive your data is though. If there's nothing special on there, I'd just reformat it. If it's *really* sensitive stuff, you have to flip and randomize the bits a few times I hear, or literally light the disk on fire.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Darik's Boot And Nuke](http://www.dban.org/)

Comment: Mark beat me to it, I missed his link before I posted.