# Completely erase hard disk

Tags: hard-drive

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Securely format a hard drive](https://superuser.com/questions/62251/securely-format-a-hard-drive)
>   [Erasing data before selling a computer](https://superuser.com/questions/4678/erasing-data-before-selling-a-computer)

I'm looking for open source bootable program to completely erase my hard disk content.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/62251/securely-format-a-hard-drive - this question is identical - in short, use DBAN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[DBAN](http://www.dban.org/) Can do this for you easily.