# Disk Formater that i can burn on CD and boot from

Tags: formatting, disc

Is there a Disc Formatter out there that i can boot into using a CD and format my Harddrive.

I know i could use fedora CD but i was wondering if there is one out there that will make sure the data is actually gone and not just there links.

Comment: Note that formatting the drive will *not* erase the data, it will only make it harder to access. If you want to completely erase personal data, see e.g. http://superuser.com/questions/4678/erasing-data-before-selling-a-computer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Dariks Boot and Nuke](http://www.dban.org/download) will format the hard drive for you and has a bootable ISO download.  If your looking for a partition manager then I suggest [Gparted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php)