# Which tool should I use to wipe free space on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, disk-utility, wipe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to quickly and effectively wipe a Win7 x64 hard drive](https://superuser.com/questions/280840/how-to-quickly-and-effectively-wipe-a-win7-x64-hard-drive)

Which tool should I use to wipe free space on Windows 7?

It should be free and preferably open source.

Comment: I don't think this is a dup, this questions is specifically about deleting the free space.

Comment: @grawity This question is not a duplicate; this question is specifically about wiping **free** space. As such, it as an answer that the other question does not: the built-in command line tool `cipher /W:C:\ `. Cipher can wipe free space on a disk (answering this person's question). Cipher *cannot* be used to wipe a hard drive (free space, used space, volumes, partition tables, boot sectors at all) making it unsuitable for the linked non-duplicate question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner). Go to Options > Settings > Wipe Free Space. It's free, but not open source.

Also, [here is a list of utilities](http://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-secure-erase-utility.htm) that should help accomplish what you want.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Good link in the post. I prefer Derrick's Burn and Nuke (DBAN), but as the website says, not for beginners

Comment: @Luke, Good stuff -- I use that, too. Definitely not for beginners. And I believe it's called Darik's Boot And Nuke.

Comment: It's some form of Derrick, Derek, Darik or Derrek

Comment: dban is for full system wiping, not free space wiping, and for that, dban is idiot proof

Comment: Yep, dban is for completely (and securely) wiping a drive, not for wiping free space. My bad.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Note that dban is not idiot-proof against all disks. dban is not suitable for use against SSDs. To [quote dban](https://dban.org/) *"It cannot detect or erase SSDs"*

Comment: I'd note *six years ago* SSDs were not as common as they are now on consumer systems. For those, apparently secure delete is the way to go