# wiping partitions from hard drive

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, wipe

I've tried using Computer Management to remove the partitions from a hard drive, but there are no options for them (other than `E:`). Is there a way to enable options to remove the partitions?

[image: Partitions]

I'm aware of DBAN, and read up on [cipher](https://superuser.com/questions/280840/how-to-quickly-and-effectively-wipe-a-win7-x64-hard-drive) but don't know what partitions are being identified here.

[image: Output]

Comment: Windows' Disk Management is fairly limited in this sense. You're probably easiest off using a third-party partitioning tool such as [GParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use and love GParted to complete such partition tasks.
"GParted is a free partition editor for graphically managing your disk partitions." http://gparted.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

I use the free(Home) version [EaseUS](http://www.partition-tool.com/?gclid=CKa2956JlLYCFQk4nAod4goAqg), it is easy to use and has never failed me.

Answer (score 0):

Good old Disk Part works like a champ. Just Google around for instructions. It's found on all versions of Windows. Careful tho ... it can wreck things if the user is not careful.