# Complete Format

Tags: windows-7, format, high-definition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Securely erasing all data from a hard drive](https://superuser.com/questions/4678/securely-erasing-all-data-from-a-hard-drive)

I am using Windows 7 64bit on normal HD drives. SATA 2.
I don't have a boot disc or copy of Windows.

I want to complete format both my HD and leave nothing on them (including Win 7) can I do this using a command line or do I need some special dos boot disc?

I also want to COMPLETELY erase the HD - I want to fully erase all my disc contents. I have heard all discs contain a history (police, forensics) I want it fully clean.

Comment: Also have a look at: http://superuser.com/questions/4678/securely-erasing-all-data-from-a-hard-drive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of tools.  All will require you to boot from CD/DVD or similar.

I used the following ones on several occasions:

- "[SecureErase](http://cmrr.ucsd.edu/people/Hughes/SecureErase.shtml)". See this article for a full description ([ZDNet article](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/storage/how-to-really-erase-a-hard-drive/129)).
- "Ultimate Boot CD" with the [DBAN](http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/dban.html) tool.

Comment: +1 DBAN if you really want to ensure all data is erased.

Answer (score 0):

A low level format format in any filesystem using an Ubuntu LiveCD should do the trick. But honestly, if it was mine, and I was in legal trouble, I would take the drive out and destroy it with a hammer.

Comment: Toss it in the lake and hope it doesn’t float back up in the spring. `:-D`