# How do I wipe an entire hard drive using the Gutmann method?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, secure-erase

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Securely erasing all data from a hard drive](https://superuser.com/questions/4678/securely-erasing-all-data-from-a-hard-drive)

Is it possible to securely wipe a hard drive [with the method outlined here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gutmann_algorithm#Method) using `dd` and little else? I have an old PC and an Ubuntu server disc which I can run a shell from, but not much is included on that.

Comment: @Nifle That question is about a Windows PC. There's not a trace of Windows left on this machine. I'm also asking specifically about the Gutmann method.

Comment: Related from other Stack Exchanges (try a little bit of searching my friend): Ask Ubuntu: [How can I securely erase a USB hard drive?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17640/how-can-i-securely-erase-a-usb-hard-drive), StackOverflow: [How do I erase my disk? (In a secure way) (Ubuntu)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/85636/how-do-i-erase-my-disk-in-a-secure-way-ubuntu) and Security: [How can I reliably erase all information on a hard drive?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/5749/how-can-i-reliably-erase-all-information-on-a-hard-drive).

Comment: The answers in that question is valid for any OS (as the OS is irrelevant at that stage).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not exactly an answer but in this day and age you are basically wasting your time trying to use the Gutmann method specifically.

[Gutmann himself](http://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~pgut001/pubs/secure_del.html#Epilogue):

> In the time since this paper was published, some people have treated
>   the 35-pass overwrite technique described in it more as a kind of
>   voodoo incantation to banish evil spirits than the result of a
>   technical analysis of drive encoding techniques. As a result, they
>   advocate applying the voodoo to PRML and EPRML drives even though it
>   will have no more effect than a simple scrubbing with random data.

Comment: So I should just do one pass from `/dev/urandom`, and maybe one from `/dev/zero` and have done with it?

Comment: `/dev/zero` is probably enough, but why not throw a random pass in there if you have time, as "Voodoo" can make you feel good sometimes, and that's important too. ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you wish the delete all the data from  drive and ensure it is all gone with no trace, if you are willing to simply burn another cd I suggest using DBAN as it will make the whole process a lot easier than using DD.

Comment: I don't have another CD…